# Handle nicely "POST Content-Length of bytes exceeds the limit of" warning

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Good day) I'm building a WordPress plugin LMS allowing user to attach their completed home assignments files via AJAX to their answers. Everything works fine, except one scenario when user's file exceeds the maximum size allowed. In this case my AJAX call returns HTML with following warning:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  POST Content-Length of XXXXX bytes exceeds the limit of XXXXX bytes in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

As this kind of warning generated on string 0 of my script, it will die and ignore any other instructions, leaving me this ugly string as a result of my call.
You basically can live with it, as the final user will not see it (just the AJAX call will not have desired result), but still **I want to know if there is a chance to jump it over and handle it nicely?**

Ok, what kind of research I've already done:

1. I found [this](http://andrewcurioso.com/blog/archive/2010/detecting-file-size-overflow-in-php.html) tutorial by Andrew Curioso, and tried to make something like this from it:

   ```
   if (isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'])) {
       if ($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > (substr(ini_get('post_max_size'), -1) * 1024 * 1024)) {
           echo 'php errors is so much fun';
       }
   }
   ```

It doesn't give the desired effect, as my script still dies with only positive effect of echoing additional string from IF statement (besides, if you try to do something like wp_send_json(errorsArray), it will not be executed).

2. Turning off displaying errors with display_errors, error_reporting. Well, it's not what I need here, as it still does not allow me to proceed with script and create custom error handler.
3. My WP_DEBUG is set to FALSE

**What kind of advice I'm not looking for** is manually editing max_upload_size, max_post_size etc. As manually editing server files is out of plugin philosophy. And anyway even if you set your max upload size to 10GB, once you will have final user trying to upload 11GB.

SO, to summarize, as we all know, this mechanism is realized on thousands of sites and apps, and I want to know how to maximize my script quality, handling this issue without overkills and bad UX.

Thank for sharing your thoughts :)

**UPD1**
Here is my AJAX call if it helps:

```
$('#post-assignment-answer').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    tinymce.triggerSave();
    var answerContent = tinymce.get('assignment_user_input_textarea').getContent();

    var answerFile = $('#assignment-file-upload')[0].files[0];

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('action', 'post_assignment_answer');
    formData.append('security', lucid_single_assignment_params.post_assignment_answer_nonce);
    formData.append('post_id', lucid_single_assignment_params.post_id);
    formData.append('answer_content', answerContent);
    formData.append('answer_file', answerFile);

    $.ajax({
        url: lucid_single_assignment_params.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

UPD2:
Added AJAX handling php

```
<?php

/**
 * Post Assignment Answer
 *
 * @version       1.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
} // Exit if accessed directly

// Create AJAX call $result
$result = array(
    'fileTypeError' => false,
    'fileSizeError' => false,
    'uploadError' => false
);

// Retrieving current post ID
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

// Retrieving WYSIWYG content
$answer_content = '';

if (! (trim($_POST['answer_content']) == '') ) {

    $answer_content = wp_kses_post($_POST['answer_content']);

}

// Updating WYSIWYG meta field
update_post_meta($post_id, '_answer_content', $answer_content);

// Check if user intends to upload a file
if (!empty($_FILES['answer_file'])) {

    // Adding timestamp to file name
    $_FILES['answer_file']['name'] = round(microtime(true)) . '_' . $_FILES['answer_file']['name'];
    $answer_file = $_FILES['answer_file'];

    // Setting up uploaded file type validation
    $supported_types = array(
        'text/plain' // .txt
    );

    $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($answer_file['name']));

    $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

    // Setting up uploaded file size validation // TODO: This should be optimized
    $allowed_size = 8388608;
    $uploaded_size = $answer_file['size'];

    // Validating, and in a case of success completing upload
    if (!in_array($uploaded_type, $supported_types)) {

        $result['fileTypeError'] = __('The type of file you\'ve provided is not allowed', 'lucidlms');

    } elseif ($uploaded_size > $allowed_size) {

        $result['fileSizeError'] = __('The size of file you\'ve provided is exceeding the maximum upload size', 'lucidlms');

    } else {

        /**
         * Override the default upload path.
         *
         * @param   array   $dir
         * @return  array
         */
        function lucidlms_assignment_upload_dir( $dir ) {
            global $user_ID;

            return array(
                'path'   => $dir['basedir'] . '/lucidlms/assignment/user' . $user_ID,
                'url'    => $dir['baseurl'] . '/lucidlms/assignment/user' . $user_ID,
                'subdir' => ''
            ) + $dir;
        }

        // Register path override
        add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'lucidlms_assignment_upload_dir' );

        $upload = wp_handle_upload($answer_file, array( 'test_form' => false ));

        // Set everything back to normal
        remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'lucidlms_user_upload_dir' );

        if (isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != 0) {

            $result['uploadError'] = sprintf(__('There was an error uploading your file. The error is: %s', 'lucidlms'), $upload['error']);

        } else {

            // Check if there is an old version of file on the server and delete it
            $existing_answer_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_answer_file', true);
            if (! empty($existing_answer_file)) {

                global $user_ID;
                $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                $existing_answer_file_name = pathinfo($existing_answer_file['file'], PATHINFO_BASENAME);
                $unlink_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/lucidlms/assignment/user' . $user_ID . '/' . $existing_answer_file_name;
                unlink($unlink_path);

            }

            // Updating post meta
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_answer_file', $upload);
        }
    }
}

wp_send_json($result);
```

Comment: Very handy, thanks. There's a small error near the start - the `substr(ini_get('post_max_size'), -1)` above should be `substr(ini_get('post_max_size'), 0,  -1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do read and *understand* what the error message is telling you:

> exceeds the limit of XXXXX bytes in **Unknown** on line 0

The error is being reported at line 0 because it is being thrown *before* your PHP code gets to execute. So you can't change the behaviour in the receiving PHP script.

The right approach is to check the size of the data [BEFORE you upload it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) (i.e. in Javascript). But beware:

1. Javascript reports the size of individual files *before* they are encoded - Base64 encoding adds an overhead of around a third, plus space for other POST attribute values and names.
2. The values configured for post_max_size is the maximum that PHP accepts. The maximum that the webserver (e.g. [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody))will accept may be lower. For a plugin, perhaps the most appropriate solution would be to allow the administrator to configure the upper limit.
3. Someone trying to subvert your security can easily bypass any checks in Javascript

Comment: i will upvote and except your answer, because checking file size on front end is the only solution I was considering as a proper one, just wanted to confirm that I'm done on the backend. thanks

Comment: I don't see why people accepts answers suggesting adjusting the maximum limits in php.ini. That does not resolve it at all. As these can always be exceeded. Say adjust the post_max_size to 100MB, what if another user posts 200MB? The problem will always occur no matter how much the limits are adjusted. A better solution would be first validate the request's content-length and continue the script as necessary, say discontinue upload or not. People don't want to wait for uploading 200MB of data only to find out that it's invalid. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @doncadavona: "A better solution would be first validate the request's content-length" - how do you suggest doing this when PHP doesn't start executing until after the file upload is complete?

Comment: @symcbean, I am not sure. I too would want to know. I guess the question now is does PHP support it? validating post size before execution, just like how it supports files per post? Why or why not? If not, I think PHP should at least halt the upload when it exceeds the maximum allowed. Say, PHP accepts <= 100MB, when user uploads 200MB, PHP immediately halts at 100MB and catches the error.

Comment: @doncadavona:the webserver chooses when to hand over the request to PHP / in the case of CGI and fast_cgi, it must buffer the entire request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/uploading-files-with-ajax--net-21077

In this at upload.php page (which is the main callback function of ajax which uploads the file) you will get the size of the image uploaded in `$_FILES["images"]["size"]`

Comment: No, in this case you will not even get $_POST and $_FILES data, this two arrays will be empty

Comment: can u please paste the code , where you have written the file upload code

Comment: updated with AJAX call, but I don't think it matters that much

Comment: Not this one.. the code where file upload code is written to which ajax is posted